# Ruby on rails - Hartl tutorial - Micropost always detected as blank but they are NOT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have realized Hartl's tutorial about ruby on rails. I've almost completed it. Everything was working and I start to change some stuff, and now I've an error that I can't understand, about a thing that was working before. I've probably change something inadvertently but can't find what!

When I try to post a micropost (with a NOT BLANK CONTENT) from my home page, it always says :

**The form contains 1 error.
    * Content can't be blank**

I have tried to launch $ bundle exec rspec spec/
And I have a new error that appear:

```
8) Micropost pages micropost creation with valid information should create a micropost
 Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Post" }.to change(Micropost, :count).by(1)
   count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:29:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So I think it is related but, I don't really understand what is the mistake so i can't understand how to solve it!

**micropost_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Micropost pages" do
subject { page }

let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { sign_in user }

describe "micropost creation" do
before { visit root_path }

describe "with invalid information" do

  it "should not create a micropost" do
    expect { click_button "Post" }.not_to change(Micropost, :count)
  end

  describe "error messages" do
    before { click_button "Post" }
    it { should have_content('error') }
  end
end

describe "with valid information" do

  before { fill_in 'micropost_content', with: "Lorem ipsum" }
  it "should create a micropost" do
    expect { click_button "Post" }.to change(Micropost, :count).by(1)
  end
end
end

describe "micropost destruction" do
before { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user) }

describe "as correct user" do
  before { visit root_path }

  it "should delete a micropost" do
    expect { click_link "delete" }.to change(Micropost, :count).by(-1)
  end
end
end
end
```

**micropost_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Micropost do

let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(content: "Lorem ipsum") }

subject { @micropost }

it { should respond_to(:content) }
it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
it { should respond_to(:user) }
its(:user) { should eq user }  

it { should be_valid }

describe "when user_id is not present" do
  before { @micropost.user_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when user_id is not present" do
  before { @micropost.user_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "with blank content" do
  before { @micropost.content = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "with content that is too long" do
  before { @micropost.content = "a" * 141 }
   it { should_not be_valid }
end
end
```

**_micropost_from.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">  
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I am really stuck with this mistake and mad at myself to not notice this mistake before. Now I've done a lot of changement and can't go back to the previous save...

Thanks a lot if you can help me , i am new with ruby on rails

**EDITING**

**MODEL : micropost.rb**

```
 class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
      validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
      validates :user_id, presence: true
    end
```

**SERVER LOG**

```
  Started POST "/microposts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-26 15:00:07 +0100
Processing by MicropostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eSMhNrhM50lg8rDcz0G6OYWW6/ssGmH+PZja2ghjJzA=", "micropost"=>{"content"=>"Try to post"}, "commit"=>"Post"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '0b245e78962e34d49d4fbb6d2e5abc804f9581e9' LIMIT 1[0m
Unpermitted parameters: content
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mrollback transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 102]]
  Rendered shared/_user_info.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_micropost_form.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_feed.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (4.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 16.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Comment: have u made :content field attr_accessible ? or we can help if u can show ur server log.

Comment: Use a version control system from now on :)

Comment: No :content isn't set as attr_accessible ! I didn't think about that because it was not in the previous version. DO you think i should do that ? I have edit my message with the dvlpmnt log. we can see "unpermitted parameters: content" but i don't know why because it is not blank we can see i've tried to write "Try to post"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using strong parameters. There should be a method called micropost_params at the bottom of your controller that declares `params.require(:micropost).permit ...` add :content to the argument list for `permit`. You want to permit :content to be mass assigned when you do `Micropost.new micropost_params`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a version of the tutorial that relies on "strong paramaters", you need to update your controller to explicitly indicate that `content` is a permitted parameter. As an aside, I think it's helpful to complete the tutorial exactly as written and then branch out when you're done.